# How to break graph to fill in the gap in pdf

Tags: graphics, pdf-format, printing

I've printed my notebook into a pdf. There is a huge gap in the left page, due to the fact that the graph in the right page isn't divided to fill in the gap.

Is there a way to fix it, preferably without resorting to do something like:

```
drawOrbits[deq1];
drawOrbits[deq2];
drawOrbits[deq3];
```

Currently, although it may not be evident, I'm doing something like:

```
drawOrbits /@ {deq1, deq2, deq3};
```

and show the result via Grid[].

[image]

Comment: May be `Print@Row@drawOrbits /@ {deq1, deq2, deq3}` is better then `Grid`?

Comment: Thanks @ybeltukov for your suggestion. I will try it tomorrow morning and will come back to you. (FWIW, if it ammends the issue and you post it as answer, I will accept it.)

Comment: I tried it but still the graph isn't broken up in 2 parts to fill in the gap. Bummer.

Comment: `CellPrint` works better then `Print`, see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Print@Row` instead of `Grid`. However by default output cells have `PageBreakWithin->False` option. So you can avoid it by `CellPrint@ExpressionCell[..., PageBreakWithin -> True]`.

Example:

```
f[a_] := Plot[#[x], {x, 0, a}, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 200] & /@ {Sin, Cos, Tan}

f /@ {10, 30, 100} // Grid
```

[image]

```
CellPrint@ExpressionCell[Row@f[#], "Output", PageBreakWithin -> True] & /@ {10, 30, 100};
```

[image]

Another possibility is to modify the stylesheet (`Format->Edit Stylesheet...` and edit appropriate cell with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>).

Comment: I will accept the answer, although I don't like much how CellPrint[] doesn't produce the same as a regular output cell (i.e., the whole image is shifted towards the left border of the page). Thanks!

Comment: @Zet It can be corrected by `ExpressionCell[Row@f[#], "Output", PageBreakWithin -> True]`, see the second snapshot. "Output" style apply all necessary properties.

Comment: Oh, I can provide "Output" as style argument to CellPrint!